# how to reduce firebase realtimeDB simultaneous connected?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app runs in background and config using only `SingleValueEvent` and `setValue()` method. I hear that even I use SingleValueEvent and setValue() one second, firebase still connecting after 5minute. and waste lot of battery.

How can I stop connected with realtimeDB jsut after finish activity?

Comment: The 5 minute delay in closing the connection is unlikely to be a battery drain. While you can call `goOffline()` yourself to close the connection earlier, that type of micro-management of the connection is not likely to gain you much battery life.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112384/firebase-realtimedb-simultaneous-connected) by Frank van Puffelen, if there are no active listeners and no writes for 5 minutes, the Firebase client auto-disconnects. It will auto-reconnects when you attach a new listener or write data. This means that will auto-reconnect `only if you create other listeners or you need to write data into the database.`

So, if there are no new listeners and you don't have to write data, you definitely don't have to worry.

And the places to remove the listeners are `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have one more question. if I use goOffline method before after 5minute gone, can I cut conntected manually with DB?

Comment: Yes, as the [offical doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#goOffline()) sais, `shuts down all connection to the Firebase Database backend until goOnline() is called`.

Comment: no I'm not yet. if this solve elegance way, I will commont here.

Comment: I solve problem.

this not work. 
final FirebaseDatabase testDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference test_ref = testDB.getReference("test");
        testDB.goOnline();
        test_ref.child("testing").setValue("testtest");
        testDB.goOffline();

Comment: but this exam work.
  testDB.goOffline(); --> 

        TimerTask mTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                testDB.goOffline();
            }
        };
        new Timer().schedule(mTask, 5000);